# React onClick function in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to trigger an onClick event in a map function, and I get this error :

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined**

How do we trigger an onClick event in a map function ?

Here is my code :

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isToggleOn: true,
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn,
        }));
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.data) {
            var recipes = this.props.data.map(function (recipe, i) {
                return (
                    <div
                        key={i}
                        className="col-8 offset-col-1 f-l relative m-t-10"
                    >
                        <div className="col-6 f-l">
                            <p className="col-8 f-l">{recipe.title}</p>
                            <button className="f-l" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                                Voir la recette
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            });
        }
        return (
            <div className="RecipeList">
                <div className="col-12">
                    {recipes}
                    <div className="both"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: your `this` points to the map function where no `handleClick` function definition exists. You need to instantiate a variable with `this` outside the `map` and use it inside your map

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an arrow function as the function given to `map` instead and `this` will be what you expect:

```
if (this.props.data) {
  var recipes = this.props.data.map((recipe, i) => {
    return <div key={i} className="col-8 offset-col-1 f-l relative m-t-10">
      <div className="col-6 f-l">
        <p className="col-8 f-l">{recipe.title}</p>
        <button className="f-l" onClick={this.handleClick}>Voir la recette</button>
      </div>
    </div>;
  });
}
```

Why this is the case is explained in detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Arrow functions don't provide their own `this` binding, but instead retains the `this` value of the enclosing lexical context.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I would tackle a similar situation.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const stuff = ["one", "two", "three"];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isToggleOn: true
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(val) {
    console.log(val);
  }

  getStuff() {
    var elements = stuff.map((value, key) => {
      return (
        <li key={key} onClick={() => this.handleClick(value)}>
          {value}
        </li>
      );
    });

    return elements;
  }
  render() {
    return <ul>{this.getStuff()}</ul>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

here is the sandbox -> https://codesandbox.io/embed/1rqw081oj7

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `this` in map arguments or arrow function.

```
 this.props.data.map(function(recipe, i) {
            return  <div key={i} className="col-8 offset-col-1 f-l relative m-t-10">
                        <div className="col-6 f-l">
                            <p className="col-8 f-l">{recipe.title}</p>
                            <button className="f-l" onClick={this.handleClick}>Voir la recette</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>;
        }, this)
```

Why?

Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to map, it will be used as
>   callback's `this` value. Otherwise, the value undefined will be used
>   as its this value.

For a better undestanding of `this` scope check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Explains what are in `this` in different context like Simple function call, as an object method, as arrow function, etc. Also explain how control the scope thanks to `bind`, `call` and `apply`.